# activeMq rar autodeployed in glassfish embedded

Tags: resources, adapter, activemq-classic, glassfish-embedded

Is it possibile to autodeploy activeMq rar into glassfish embedded? I tried many ways using glassfish-embedded-all-3.1b11 upto 3.2b06 but had no luck. In particular, I'd like to use javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer api instead of dynamically deploying to org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFish.